# How to call dynamic id in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm generating radio inputs with a custom `id` like this:

```
foreach($paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] as $custompay) {
    $html .= '<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$custompay.'">&nbsp;<b>'.$custompay.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

I am using the same id below in the jQuery selector but when it's dynamic it's not working:

```
jQuery("#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay").click(function() {
    jQuery("#cnp_CreditCard_div").hide();                   
    jQuery("#cnp_eCheck_div").hide();
    jQuery("#cnp_Custompay_div").show();
});
```

How can I call the that dynamic id in that selector?

In  $custompay we will get some thing like this **custom,custom1,custom2** based on that id should be **cnp_payment_method_selection_customay,cnp_payment_method_selection_customay1,cnp_payment_method_selection_customay2**

by using below code

```
foreach($paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] as $custompay) {
                $html .='<script type="text/javascript">
                        var simple = "cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'";
                        alert(simple);

                        </script>'; 

                    //print_r($custompayment);
                $html .= '<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$custompay.'">&nbsp;<b>'.$custompay.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';

                }
                $html .= '</span>';
```

Where my var simple is getting Id which i want but now i want pass that variable in the place of `<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$custompay.'">`

variable i want to call place of id as variable

Comment: Did you try checking how the rendered HTML looks like?

Comment: when dynamic added use event delegation

Comment: I have one id but different names like #cnp_payment_method_selection_customay,#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay1,#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay2,#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay3 some thing like this i want based on selection hit the id

Comment: Where are you appending that input type in dom?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'starts with' selector to identify the elements:

```
$('input[id^=cnp_payment_method_selection_]')
```

This will return you all the elements that have ids starting with `cnp_payment_method_selection_`.

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: I don't want all with particular variable only i want  $custompay

Answer (score 0):

They're not same.

```
id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'" 
jQuery("#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay").click(function(){
```

You can get id with data parameters.

```
foreach($paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] as $custompay) {
                    $html .= '<input type="radio" data-id="'.$custompay.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$custompay.'">&nbsp;<b>'.$custompay.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                   }

jQuery(".cnp_payment_method_selection_customay").click(function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
        });
```

Comment: yes they are not same, i want generated id to call in selector

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.add](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method to create a dynamic selector ( You can iterate through $paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] and add the element to the selector  )

```
var selector = $();//an empty selector 
foreach($paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] as $custompay) {
  selector.add('#cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay);//add a $custompay to the selector
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: you are right @DonaldDuck , I've added some context

Answer (score 0):

As I am able to see.
I think you trying to generate some inut type with different ids and after that you will insert that dynamic input type to you any page element.

So If you are generating dynamic element and appending to DOM then you can't give direct click event to them, that will not work.
For that you need to reference through parent element and need to use .on.

If you generating elements as like below.

```
foreach($paymentMethods['CustomPayment'] as $custompay) {
    $html .= '<input type="radio" id="cnp_payment_method_selection_'.$custompay.'" name="cnp_payment_method_selection" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;" value="'.$custompay.'">&nbsp;<b>'.$custompay.'</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
}
```

And let after that you appending your $html to element having class container as like below

```
$(".container").html($html);
```

Then you are giving click event of input you need to give using .on and referencing from parent( here .container) as like below.

```
$(".container").on('click','#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay', function() {
 // your stuff here

});
```

Comment: but in this id $(".container").on('click','#cnp_payment_method_selection_customay', function() {
 // your stuff here

});

Comment: where cnp_payment_method_selection_customay where is different from each radio

Comment: using $(this) variable in click event you can get $(this).val();

but I think you want differentiate on the basis of clicked event then you don't need to set different id. Just use your class like

<input type="radio" class="cnp_payment_method_selection" value="'.$custompay.'" />

and give click event using 
$(".container').on("click', 'cnp_payment_method_selection', function() {
// your stuff
var clicked_rd_value = $(this).val(); 
});

using clicked radio value you can whatever you want.